# Have edit privileges changed?

Tags: support, editing

Another user edited [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/9599/1771). I saw a spiffy new "Edit (1)" link instead of just "Edit", clicked it, reviewed that user's edits, and approved them.

But instead of the edits being approved, and instead of me being able to edit the question myself (as used to happen), my approval now needs an additional approval from another editor, and there's no avenue for me to put in my own edit. Is this intentional? Did something change, or is this how edits have always worked? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't do anything wrong. For a while now, we've been requiring multiple approvals for suggested edits on Stack Overflow; that was recently expanded to the rest of the network.

If you see other improvements that can be made when reviewing an edit, click the "Improve" button and make them - this has the side effect of also immediately approving the edit suggestion.

Comment: What if I approve the edit, then notice additional improvements? (I don't have any posts to test this on, so I can't tell if there's still an Improve button in that scenario.)

Answer (score 2):

I asked the team about this, and they've made some changes to the way approvals/rejections work. This is new behavior network wide.

See Shog9's response on meta.StackOverflow: [It takes two to tango](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/151586#151586)

Essentially, the new rules are:

- Network-wide: two reviews per edit suggestion.
- Stack Overflow: three reviews per edit suggestion.